# Is it possible to pass Login username details of shinyproxy to shiny app?

Tags: r, shiny, shinyproxy

Can the login details be passed from shinyproxy to shiny app?
I want to write sql query to filter content and display the data that pertains to that user alone.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is perfectly possible. As the [configuration](https://www.shinyproxy.io/documentation/configuration/#ldap) page of the manual mentions, when a user is authenticated, the following environment variables will be available in any Shiny application launched by the user:

- SHINYPROXY_USERNAME: the name of the user, as used when logging in
- SHINYPROXY_USERGROUPS: the groups the authenticated user is a member of, as a comma-separated value

From within the Shiny app, you can then query this information using

```
userName <- Sys.getenv("SHINYPROXY_USERNAME")
```

and use that downstream in your SQL queries.